# Powershell: is there a limit to the number of output file types I can have?

Tags: error-handling, powershell-2.0, file-conversion

I've got a Powershell (2.0) script that uses `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat` to recursively open a series of html files in Word, then save as Word and Text using the `wdFormatDocument` and `wdFormatDOSText` parameters, respectively. The script contains a separate function for each document type.

Yesterday, the requirements changed, and I now need to output an RTF document as well. I added the `$saveFormatRTF` variable

```
$saveFormatDoc = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat], "wdFormatDocument"); 
$saveFormatTxt = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat], "wdFormatDOSText"); 
$saveFormatRTF = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat], "wdFormatRTF");
```

and got the following errors.

```
Unable to find type [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is l
oaded.
At C:\users\x46332\Desktop\cgc\CGC002.PS1:68 char:76
+ $saveFormatDoc = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat] <<<< , "wdFormatDocument");
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Offic...rd.WdSaveFormat:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Unable to find type [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is l
oaded.
At C:\users\x46332\Desktop\cgc\CGC002.PS1:69 char:76
+ $saveFormatTxt = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat] <<<< , "wdFormatDOSText");
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Offic...rd.WdSaveFormat:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Unable to find type [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is l
oaded.
At C:\users\x46332\Desktop\cgc\CGC002.PS1:70 char:76
+ $saveFormatRTF = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat] <<<< , "wdFormatRTF");
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Offic...rd.WdSaveFormat:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Running the script converting JUST to Word and Text works fine. Running the RTF by itself it just fine. However, anytime I combine RTF in a script with other output formats, ALL output formats referenced in the script come up as "not found". Does RTF need to be exported on its own? Is there a limit to how many output file types I can have in one script (they're all separate functions, though)? Is there some parameter I'm not setting?

I have [verified that the member names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238158.aspx) for output are correct, and I've scanned [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for clues, but can't find anything that would cause this behavior, especially the unpredictable results when adding RTF to the mix. Any ideas?

Comment: If I start up a fresh Powershell 2 session, execute `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word")`, and then copy-paste your 3 lines of code, it works.  All individually works as well.  Sorry, cannot reproduce in any way.  For me, it uses `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some further testing, a few days later I was able to convert as expected with no difficulties. I also tested converting to every format [listed here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/bshukla/archive/2010/07/29/how-to-convert-a-word-document-to-other-formats-using-powershell.aspx) with a single script...and except for some funky output formatting on special characters, everything worked great.

So, I'm guessing there's no limit, and my testing seems to bear out that theory.